# Code not showing up when opening Visual Studio from Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a newcomer when it comes to Unity. I was following along with this online course. At one point, I had to write a C# script. So, I created one and doubled clicked it to edit it with Visual Studio. However when Visual Studio opened, all I could see was a essentially a blank screen. I couldn't see any code. Does anyone know the fix?

Thank you

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot with what's happening?

Comment: Have you tried "Assets" => "open c# project" in Unity? This might generate the needed visual studio project files

Answer (score 0):

Did you create it inside like this ... In Unity>ProjectWindow>AssetsFolder>RightClick>Create>C#Script.Then double click to open it.It will open up a script containing Start() and Update() method.If you could not find this.Restart and try.This is to test and try script for Unity scripting.

Answer (score 0):

So this is way too late for the original post but maybe someone else will find this useful. So you did everything you were supposed to and even see the automated code with everything it should have in the inspector, but when you go and run the code whether clicking the actual script in the asset>scripts or clicking the open button in the inspector the same problem persists... blank uneditable screen.

I think you may just need to run updates on Visual Studio and/or if on a Mac maybe you need to log back into Microsoft. To do this just click the Visual Studio tab and click check for updates. Usually, you will also see an update suggestion in the top center of the screen. Run the updates and let it restart visual studio. Once you reopen visual studio at this time if you are on a Mac it should ask you to log into Microsoft. Your code might show up now.